# How to loop over the dict and add the values of similar items

Tags: python

How can I loop over the below dict and create another dict where the values of similar items are added?

```
file_dict = {'abc.mp3': 10, 'abc.jpg': 20, 'abc.mp4': 30, 'xyz.mp3': 40, 'mno.mp3': 40, 'xyz.jpg': 30}
```

**Expected output:**

```
added_dict = {'mp3': 90, 'jpg': 50, 'mp4': 30}
```

Comment: How is your `file_dict` dictionary having multiple keys with same name? Keys in dictionary are unique

Comment: there's no way your original dict can exist

Comment: The original dict could be instantiated this way, but it would keep the last inserted key for similar ones.

Comment: Short answer: you can't, because your `file_dict` doesn't actually look like that.  Long answer: use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and come up with a way of generating your original data that doesn't rely on putting it in a dictionary first

Comment: I thought I can simplify the question but I was wrong. I have updated the question and the expected output should be the same. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the solution by @Ajax1234 is too much *Python-Fu* for you, you can try this one:

```
file_dict = {'abc.mp3': 10, 'abc.jpg': 20, 'abc.mp4': 30, 'xyz.mp3': 40, 'mno.mp3': 40, 'xyz.jpg': 30}

added_dict = {}
for k, v in file_dict.items():
    temp_k = k.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    res = added_dict.setdefault(temp_k, 0)
    added_dict[temp_k] += v
print(added_dict)   # -> {'mp3': 90, 'jpg': 50, 'mp4': 30}
```

Comment: Maybe `k.rsplit('.', 1)` is better?

Comment: @DDGG yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import os

file_dict = {'abc.mp3': 10, 'abc.jpg': 20, 'abc.mp4': 30, 'xyz.mp3': 40, 'mno.mp3': 40, 'xyz.jpg': 30}

added_dict = {}
for k, v in file_dict.items():
    ext = os.path.splitext(k)[-1][1:]
    added_dict[ext] = added_dict.setdefault(ext, 0) + v

print(added_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_dict = {'abc.mp3': 10, 'abc.jpg': 20, 'abc.mp4': 30, 'xyz.mp3': 40, 'mno.mp3': 40, 'xyz.jpg': 30}

some_dict = {}
for key, value in file_dict.iteritems():
    #   Formatting your key.
    formatted_key = key.split('.')[-1]

    #   If key exists, update data.
    if formatted_key in some_dict:
        some_dict[formatted_key] += value
    #   If not, create the key.
    else:
        some_dict[formatted_key] = value

print some_dict
```

Comment: Nitpick: going with `[-1]` is safer imho.